# Dealing with multi threading in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, nspersistentstore

In my project I have used **NSOperationQueues** to perform different task in core data. In this some operations are performed in performBlock and some other in PerformBlockAndWait which is called in background Queue or mainQueue.In this there is main context and background context to deal with different threads.When iam logging out from my application I want clear all details stored in core data and to stop all the threads currently running.

**In short** : When logging out from application I need to clear all data stored in coredata and then to stop all background threads running. how can I achieve this ?

Comment: what is your  question ?

Comment: When logging out from application i need to clear all data stored in coredata and then to stop all background threads running.

Comment: if ([operationQueue operationCount] > 0) {
    [operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
} This will set **isCancelled** property of operation to YES.

Comment: Im creating this operationQueues when calling API and then the API results are stored in core data.So where shall i call cancelAllOperations.

Comment: The NSOperationQueue class regulates the execution of a set of NSOperation objects. After being added to a queue, an operation remains in that queue until it is explicitly canceled or finishes executing its task. **If you think your operation will going on when you are performing logout, then simply call a method from your logout function.**

Comment: [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] cancelAllOperations]; is this the method you tell?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129424/discussion-between-user1728987-and-wolverine).

Answer (score 0):

Use app will terminate method to do your task. It will run when the app is about to terminate

```
func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {

    print("applicatoinWillTerminate")

    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```